# XCode texture atlases

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am developing a game and in the main menu I would like to make an animation. I thought it would be better to use an atlas to incorporate all the images for this animation, but I have found that making images from a texture atlas is not as easy as making SKTextures. A big part of my game is already developed so I would not want to make huge changes in the controller in order to be able to incorporate the SKTexture in the mainmenu

I just want to know, is there a way to create get the UIImage from a SKTexture?, or is there a way so `[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageInsideAtlas"]]` works?

Comment: No reason your name needs to be like this, by the way. Can just use: [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageInsideAtlas"]

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to display the texture offscreen and essentially do a snapshot to a UIImage:

```
-(UIImage*)snapshot
{
    // Captures SpriteKit content!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

Reference: http://eppz.eu/blog/uiimage-from-spritekit-scene/

Answer (score 0):

Texture atlas was built to work with Sprite Kit, so it offers you SKTextures instead of UIImages. I afraid, there is no easy way to get UIImages from texture atlas.

Consider loading SKTextures from texture atlas and use them to animate SKSpriteNode.